# how create circle drawables like below

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would like to create drawables like the following so that I can adjust the colour at run time.

[image: Drawable when the colour is selected]
[image: Drawable when the colour is not selected]

I can easily create the drawable with a stroke around a colour but all it does is create the line on the edge of the circle, but I need to have the white line on the inside with the same colour as the center on the outside?

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) is what you are looking for.

You basically override the onDraw method of your view and call `drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint)` with the parameters on the link.